# Google Chrome won't start

Tags: google-chrome, crash

When I try to start Google Chrome, it starts but it's just open for like 2-4 sec and then it's closing again..

When I try to start it from Terminal, i get this message?

```
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[8820:8820:0405/095558:ERROR:background_mode_manager_aura.cc(14)] Not implemented reached in virtual void BackgroundModeManager::EnableLaunchOnStartup(bool)
Minnesegmentsfeil (core dumped)
```

I'm not new to Ubuntu, but new to problems like this... Somebody who can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to re-install chrome like this for 64bit

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome

sudo apt-get install libxss1 libappindicator1 libindicator7
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
```

OR 32bit

```
sudo apt-get install libxss1 libappindicator1 libindicator7
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
```

This will also install a PPA to stay up to date.

Comment: By the way there's also the official [Google repository](http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/)

Comment: This is the official repo https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb is the official download page

Comment: Repository it's an improper term, that's the official debian package, a repository is something else

Comment: No it is the .deb from Google.com it contains the repo information and will update automatically, I installed the same one and Google.com is listed as the repo in my software sources.

Comment: Ok, I see, I didn't know the installer would add the repository as well. Upvoted anyway :)